# Get DNS SRV record using JNDI

Tags: java, dns, jndi, srv

I am trying to get SRV records from a DNS server using JNDI.

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "dns://dns.server.com");
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes("_sip._udp", new String [] { "SRV" });
return attributes;
```

But when trying to get attributes I get the following exception

> DNS error [Root exception is
>   java.net.PortUnreachableException:
>   ICMP Port Unreachable]; remaining name
>   '_sip._udp'

I have verified host -t srv _sip._udp.server.com returns valid SRV record.

Any reason as why this might happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the following: `dns.server.com` not a valid DNS server, does not have a SRV record for `_sip._udp`, the DNS service does not respond on port 53 (standard DNS port) or your Java code is wrong.

To diagnose DNS server troubles, you could try `host -t SRV _sip._udp.server.com dns.server.com` or `dig @dns.server.com -t SRV _sip._udp.server.com` to confirm that the server works.

If `host` or `dig` return the expected entry, try the following changes to your code:

Change:

```
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "dns://dns.server.com");
```

To:

```
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "dns:");
```

(i.e., just use your OS's standard DNS resolution)

Change:

```
ctx.getAttributes("_sip._udp", new String [] { "SRV" });
```

To:

```
ctx.getAttributes("_sip._udp.domain.com", new String [] { "SRV" });
```

as SRV record require a domain name to search, so you'd end up with:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes("_sip._udp.domain.com", new String [] { "SRV" });
return attributes;
```