# access DNS TTL for SRV & TXT records when using JNDI DNS

Tags: java, dns, jndi

How can I access the DNS TTL for SRV & TXT records when using Java JNDI DNS?

I'm [accessing DNS records using the JNDI DnsContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473320/68037).   I read (not sure where now) that SOA records could be an option.  I'm not a DNS expert and couldn't tell how to get at the SOA (from my provider Namecheap).  Anyway, I thought each record type has its own TTL so I expected that should come back inside both SRV & TXT records.

P.S.  I've used the [dnsjava](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473320/68037) library and could easily get at TTL from both SRV and TXT records.  But I was hoping to use JNDI instead and avoid an external dependency.

Comment: Where you able to get this to work?  I'd like to do something similar on Android, but it's looking like that's not possible without dnsjava.

Comment: @GrandAdmiral, I'm still not able to get at TTL data from JNDI DNS.